# wordpress: Can you preview what a page would look like as if you weren't logged in?

Tags: wordpress

I have a page with different behavior for users/non-users. If I'm logged in to the admin account to make changes or something, I can see the version of the page for a logged in user, but is there a way to see what the page would look like as if I were not logged in (or as if I were a different user) without having to actually log out or switch accounts?

Comment: You can open your site in an incognito window as a non-logged user

Comment: this is probably the best solution if there isn't a built it one